# Fill input boxes in website with Javascript (Chrome console) improvement issues

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I have already created a script for a website where it updates the input boxes based on the header (h3) above it.

To avoid having multiple ifs, I have decided to create a dictionary instead but I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')

My first code was:

```
    var k = 1;
    for (var i = 2; i < 29; i++) {
    var j = i-k;
    if(document.querySelector('h3:nth-child('+i+')'))
    {
        var value = document.querySelector('h3:nth-child('+i+')').innerHTML;
        if( value.includes("Value1"))
        {
            document.querySelector('#q'+j).value = "random_value1";
        }
        else if( value.includes("Value2"))
        {
            document.querySelector('#q'+j).value = "random_value2";
        }
        else if( value.includes("Value3"))
        {
            document.querySelector('#q'+j).value = "random_value3";
        }           
        else
        {
            // do nothing
        }
        k = k+1;
    }
}
```

and it works fine. My code with the dictionary is here:

**Code Snippet**

```js
const myself = {
  Value1: "random_value1",
  Value2: "random_value2",
  Value3: "random_value3"

};

var k = 1;

for (var key in myself) {
  console.log(key)
  console.log(myself[key])
  for (var i = 2; i < 29; i++) {
    var j = i - k;
    if (document.querySelector('h3:nth-child(' + i + ')')) {
      var value = document.querySelector('h3:nth-child(' + i + ')').innerHTML;
      if (value.includes(key)) {
        console.log("true")
        document.querySelector('#q' + j).value = myself[key];
      } else {
        // do nothing
      }
      k = k + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="html_form">&nbsp;<br>
  <h3>Value1:</h3>
  <input type="text" name="q1" id="q1">
  <h3>Value2:</h3>
  <input type="text" name="q2" id="q2">
</div>
```

Comment: It would be beneficial if you could edit the question to show an example of the HTML, as I'm certain there will be a better way to implement what you require, but it depends on the page structure.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan To be honest I found a random website after researching for form website in one page. I firstly though AI would be amazing to use but I have started working on this script first. Based on the two codes, I do not understand what is wrong with the second one.

Comment: Thanks for adding the HTML. I created an answer for you below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the HTML you provided, this can be simplified. Firstly, as the `input` are the following sibling elements of the `h3` elements, then you can simply use `nextElementSibling()` instead of having to hack together a selector string, or muddying the HTML with unnecessary attributes.

In addition, you can use a single loop through the object properties finding matching `h3` elements and performing the update if required.

Here's a working example:

```js
const h3 = document.querySelectorAll('.html_form > h3');
const myself = { Value1: "random_value1", Value2: "random_value2", Value3: "random_value3" };

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(myself)) {
  const target = [...h3].find(el => el.textContent.includes(key));
  if (target) {
    target.nextElementSibling.value = value;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="html_form">
  &nbsp;<br>
  
  <h3>Value1:</h3>
  <input type="text" name="q1" id="q1">

  <h3>Value2:</h3>
  <input type="text" name="q2" id="q2">
</div>
```

Comment: I will test that. Does it work if it contains the key (not equals)?

Comment: I did not notice the find before. It does work. Stunning work :)